# failed creating Unix socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix, unix-socket

Please i will first like to state that, i don't know how to program in C. This is a software which i am trying to get running that gives me this error. So the name of the executable file is called BGPdb_ctl2 which is part of a big program.This program was written about 9 years ago. When BGPdb_ctl2 is run by the main program, i have an error which is under the domain of "failed creating unix socket", so i went to the src of the program to take a look at the source code of BGPdb_ctl2 and find where "failed in connect" is. which is here :

```
ret = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, addr_len);
if ( ret == -1 ) {
    err( EXIT_FAILURE, "failed in connect" );
}
```

So i don't really know why -1 is returned. Maybe it's an old deprecated method etc ? no idea but it seemed to work 8 years ago from the developers. I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

**This is the full code :**

```
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/un.h>
 #include <err.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>


 extern int errno;

 int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
     int ret;
     int sock;
     struct sockaddr_un addr;
     socklen_t addr_len;
     char command[64];
     int length;
     char buff[128];

     /* CHECK: Add a getopts thing here... right now, I'm lazy... */

     sock = socket( AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
     if ( sock == -1 ) {
         err( EXIT_FAILURE, "failed creating unix_socket" );
     }

     memset( &addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un) );
     addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
     strcpy( addr.sun_path, DBDIR );
     strcat( addr.sun_path, "loader.socket" );

     addr_len = sizeof(addr.sun_family) + 
     strlen(addr.sun_path);

     ret = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, addr_len);
     if ( ret == -1 ) { 
         err( EXIT_FAILURE, "failed in connect" );
     }

     if ( argc != 2 ) {
         errx( EXIT_FAILURE, "usage: prefserv-ctl command\n\tcommand\t"
              "load - load update files\n\n" );
     }

     snprintf( command, 64, "%s\n", argv[1] );
     ret = send( sock, command, strlen(command), 0 );
     memset ( &command, 0,sizeof(command));
     memset ( &buff, 0,sizeof(command));
     while( (length = recv(sock, buff, 128, 0)) > 0 ) {
         sscanf( buff, "%63s", command );
         if ( strcmp( command, "done" ) == 0 ) {
             break;
             }
         }

     return 0;
 }
```

**Update**

This is a file that also has something to do with the **loader.socket** The file is called
**loader.server**

```
 ret = bind(unix_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &unix_addr, unix_addr_len);
    if ( ret == -1 ) {
        warn( "failed in bind" );
        return ((void *) NULL);
    }

 ret = listen( unix_sock, 1 /* Number to log */ );
    if ( ret == -1 ) {
        warn( "failed in bind" );
        return ((void *) NULL);
```

Please if you need more code, don't hesitate to ask. Any trival debugging tips are greatly welcome.

Comment: Check the value of `errno` to see *why* it failed. Add a call to something like `perror("socket");` before you bail and see what it prints.

Comment: @FatalError: `err` does `perror`.

Comment: Does it print anything else besides "failed creating unix_socket"?

Comment: Sounds perhaps like you've run out of fds? If you're sure that `socket()` is where it's failing, that's pretty much the only "normal" thing can cause a problem.

Comment: @FatalError Sorry, that was the wrong method, i changed it to the right one that generated the error which is :**failed in connect**

So in my console i see **failed in connect** when i run it. Now i will add perror as you said, like this ? ''perror("socket");'' after the if statement ?

Comment: @n.m. please see my reply to FatalError

Comment: @FatalError output: 'socket: No such file or directory
BGPdb-ctl2: failed in connect: No such file or directory'

Comment: `err` already does `perror` for you. There's no need to add your own. That's why you are seeing "No such file or directory" twice.

Comment: The error means that no one listens on the other end of the socket, there's nothing to connect to.

Comment: @n.m. Sorry if i sound too noobish, I don't even know who is to listen at the other end of the socket.Maybe another instance of the big program running ? any ideas how i may find it ?

Comment: What is `DBDIR`? Does the file  `DBDIR/loader.socket` exist while trying to `connect()`? Does the client has rights to open it?

Comment: Look for calls to `bind` or `accept` shortly after creating an AF_UNIX socket. Also check that the file pointed to actually exists.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: `bind()`? `accept()`? In the client?

Comment: You are calling a function named `connect`. What do you want to connect *to*? I surely don't know. A program that listens on a socket normally calls `bind`, `listen` and `accept`. If you have such a program, and it `bind`s to the same address you are trying to `connect`, try running it.

Comment: @n.m.: It's an `AF_UNIX` socket the client tries to connect to. This socket is represented by a file and as `connect()`ing seems to result in `ENOENT` ("*No such file or directory*"), this file either does not exist or is not accessable by the user that runs the client.

Comment: @alk you have a point. That file doesnt exist. However, DBDIR, is the directory where it's suppose to be in on my computer. I searched the source directory where i do ./configure etc, i can't even find the loader.socket anywhere. The only thing close to "loader" is loader-server.c

Comment: @alk: Yes, it's a file. It does not exist because nobody has created it by calling `bind`.

Comment: As the client code tries to connect to the Unix-Domain-Socket-Endpoint of this AF_UNIX typed socket it most probably is created by a server module. This server module needs to use exactly the same name as the client. Either it's hard coded or configurable. It shall appear as the value of a member of a `struct sockaddr_un` passed to `bind()` by the server code.

Comment: @n.m. i doubt if loader.socket is a generated file ? Because the package given to me by the developer is assumed complete.

Comment: It's created on run-time. Please, see my last comment.

Comment: It could be. Look for calls to `bind`.

Comment: How is `unix_addr` initialised?